# Расположение модального окна

Tags: html, css

Есть адаптивное модальное окно, на компе оно строго по середине, а на телефоне получается сверху, помогите подправить код.Выставлял margin-top но на телефоне с летает и все равно сверху распологается.

```css
.modalDialog {
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20% auto;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}

.close {
  background: #7f1a1a;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close">x</a>
    <h2>Оставьте заявку</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
      <input placeholder="Введите ваше имя" name="name" class="name1" type="text">
      <input placeholder="Введите ваш номер" name="number" class="number1" type="text">
      <input placeholder="Введите ваш email" name="email" class="email1" type="text">
      <p><input value="Отправить" class="SuperButton" type="submit"></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#openModal" class="to_contact">Нажмите</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.modalDialog {
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
}
.flex-modalDialog{
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog .modal-window {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}

.close {
  background: #7f1a1a;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
      <div class="flex-modalDialog">
        <div class="modal-window">
          <a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close">x</a>
          <h2>Оставьте заявку</h2>
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
            <input placeholder="Введите ваше имя" name="name" class="name1" type="text">
            <input placeholder="Введите ваш номер" name="number" class="number1" type="text">
            <input placeholder="Введите ваш email" name="email" class="email1" type="text">
            <p><input value="Отправить" class="SuperButton" type="submit"></p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<a href="#openModal" class="to_contact">Нажмите</a>
```

Если не менять ваш подход.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то я ломал голову.

Comment: а как чуть увеличить само окно т.е его размер width

Comment: Конкретнее, что вы имеете в виду)

Comment: Поменяйте 200px на то что нужно

Comment: спасибо , просто не увидел